# Mobile device friendly games?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile

**What does it mean ?**
What do I have to take care of for that ?
I am programming a game in AS3 that can be played with "mouse clicks" only. *Is that mobile device friendly already ?* Or is that "Touch Friendly" ?

I guess:

```
// touch / mobile un-friendly
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

// touch / mobile friendly
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work for simple interactions. If you want something more complex (gestures, etc) you have to use touch events (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html). For more performance on mobile I suggest you use a framework like Starling (http://gamua.com/starling/).